# g++ error: field has incomplete type

Tags: c++, oop, g++

I'm trying to work  with inner classes. I need to call get function from the nested class. What am I doing wrong? Thank you for your time!

```
   class Discriminant
{
private:
    float d;
public:
    void calcDiscr(int temp_a,int temp_b,int temp_c)
    {
        d = (temp_b^2)-4*temp_a*temp_c;
    }
    float get_d()
    {
        return d;
    }
    class Result
    {
    private:
        float x1,x2;
    public:
        Discriminant tempObject1;//here comes the error
        void calcResult(int temp_a,int temp_b,int temp_c)
        {
            cout<<"object's d = "<<tempObject1.get_d();
            x1 = (-temp_b+sqrt(tempObject1.get_d()))/2*temp_a;
            x2 = (-temp_b-sqrt(tempObject1.get_d()))/2*temp_a;
        }
        void displayResult()
        {
            cout<<endl<<"x1 = "<<x1;
            cout<<endl<<"x2 = "<<x2;
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: And what _is_ the error?

Comment: field ‘tempObject1’ has incomplete type ‘Solution::Discriminant’

Comment: Could you show how Result is actually created and used? There are plenty of possible solutions, but we can't tell which ones will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the compiler reads the

```
Discriminant tempObject1;//here comes the error
```

line, the definition of `Discriminant` has not been fully parsed (hence the `incomplete type` error); which only ends with the final `;`, closing the `class Discriminant` statement.

Theoretical solutions that do not require `Discriminant` to be a fully-defined type are to make `tempObject1` either:

1. `Discriminant*`
2. `Discriminant&`

Of which only solution #1 is feasible.

Comment: Alternatively he could just not define the nested class until after the semicolon..

Answer (score 0):

That is your code, that doesn't compile:

```
class Discriminant
{
    // etc.

    class Result
    {
        // etc.
        Discriminant tempObject1; //here comes the error
    };
};
```

The problem is, like reported by [haavee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26083/haavee), that Discriminant is not fulled parsed (and thus incomplete) when you try to make it a member of Result.

One solution is to make tempObject1 a pointer, instead of a value.

Another solution is to define Result after Discriminant (I assume you want to keep the IMHO awful inner class style). The code becomes:

```
class Discriminant
{
    // etc.

    class Result;
};

class Discriminant::Result
{
    // etc.
    Discriminant tempObject1; // No error!
};
```

This should solve your compilation problem.

P.S.: I missed the first part of your question:

> I'm trying to work with inner classes. I need to call get function from the nested class.

I hope your using nested classes is not an attempt to use Java's bizarre version's.

If you expect your inner class to have a pointer/reference to the outer class like in Java, you will be disappointed. This is a Java peculiarity. C++ and C# don't implement this bizarre feature. You'll have to pass the pointer manually.